# JMockit Deencapsulation to set multiple fields of parameterized interfaces

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, jmockit

I have a service Impl class which has the following 2 fields autowired:

```
@Service
public class OServiceImpl implements OService {

@Autowired
private MessageSender<EntityA> messageBrokerEventProducerA;

@Autowired
private MessageSender<EntityB> messageBrokerEventProducerB;
```

I want to write junits where I can mock implementation of above 2 interfaces using jmockit.

```
public class TestClass {

@Autowired
OService oService;

private static class MockMessageBrokerEventProducerA implements MessageSender<EntityA> {

    @Override
    public void sendMessage(EntityA message) {
        System.out.println("mock A called");
    }
    
}

private static class MockMessageBrokerEventProducerB implements MessageSender<EntityB>{

    @Override
    public void sendMessage(EntityB message) {
        System.out.println("mock B called");
    }
    
}

private MessageSender<A> mockMessageBrokerEventProducerA;
private MessageSender<B> mockMessageBrokerEventProducerB;

@BeforeEach
public void mockSetuUp() {
    
    mockMessageBrokerEventProducerB = new MockMessageBrokerEventProducerB();
    mockMessageBrokerEventProducerA = new MockMessageBrokerEventProducerA();
    Deencapsulation.setField(oService, mockMessageBrokerEventProducerA);
    Deencapsulation.setField(oService, mockMessageBrokerEventProducerB);
}
```

The above set up does not work, it throws an error :
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: More than one instance field to which a value of type ....can be assigned exists in the class.
It works well whenever there is only one interface autowired in impl class and mocking that one. Above error is thrown whenever there is autowiring of more than 1 interface (**same interface with generics**) in impl class. How should I solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with following:

```
Deencapsulation.setField(oService, "messageBrokerEventProducerA", 
mockMessageBrokerEventProducerA);
```